# Could a question on trump blocking people on twitter work?

Tags: discussion

I'm skeptical that Trump has blocked many of the people reporting it, or that he even reads any messages on twitter at all, could a question here work asking about this?

[Here](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-intersect/wp/2017/06/07/how-getting-blocked-by-trump-on-twitter-became-a-badge-of-honor/?utm_term=.10cb23b0b8a5) is an article full of "thinks" and "may haves", evidence that would convince me that he has blocked a person would be a quote from Trump, or something stronger than a screenshot.

Comment: So would the question be about if Trump blocked particular claimants, or if he's just blocking a lot of people in general?

Comment: Personal opinion is that this sort of blocking seems entirely plausible; dunno why Trump'd not block people he doesn't like.  But I dunno if Trump's social media drama makes for an interesting topic.  Not to say it's off-topic, just I don't see the appeal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question was "Did Trump block someone because they made a joke about ice cream?" it would be off-topic, because it is about the motivation of an individual, and we can't ever know.

If the question was "Did Trump (or his social media assistants) block VoteVets? And I won't accept a screenshot as sufficient evidence." it is probably on-topic, but it will never get answered, because Trump is incredible unlikely to comment on it, and no-one else will be able to provide evidence you trust.

If the question is "Does Trump (or his social media assistants) ban a lot of people?"... it's a bit vague. Can we find someone who says he blocks "hundreds" or something more specific? That again, would be on-topic, but hard to answer.

Comment: Agreed.  The only people who would be able to provide definite proof would be Twitter or Trump himself, and I don't see either of them happening.